# Midi not Working after installing Jack

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack, midi

I am currently trying to run **FlStudio 20** (with the help of **wine64**) on **Ubuntu 21.10**. Its mostly working surprisingly good. The Only Problem I am unable to solve Is my Audio & Midi.

With the basic pulseaudio drivers the sound was extremly glitchy and buffering, or the latency was just trash.

So I tried to install Jack along Pulseaudio so I can hear the Sound of my other Applications while using FL Studio.
For the Installation I followed this Tutorial: https://github.com/jackaudio/jackaudio.github.com/wiki/WalkThrough_User_PulseOnJack

**Everything Is working very well except my Midi**. Since this Install no Software is able to use my Midi Keyboard. My Midi Keyboard gets recognized but seems to get used by the alsa driver.
Now I wonder how I will be able to use Midi with PulseAudio on top of Jack!?

Or is there a way to use Jack only but still using My DAW and Other Software at the same Time so I can use qjackctl again? (Qjackctl is unusable after the steps in the tutorial BTW)

Great Thanks for reading my Question, I would be so happy If I can finally use FL Studio on Ubuntu.
I swear Gaming on Linux is so easy compared with Audio/Music-Production on Linux

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution for my Problem!!!**

I just removed all the Jack Stuff from my System and installed pipewire.

Pipewire is a package to let pulseaudio work with higher sample rates with lower delay and higher cpu usage. With pipewire I just run my Wine emulated FL Studio 20 and my MIDI Devices Worked and the Audio ist now as good as on windows. Only problem: The Latency of MIDI is a bit higher then with Asio4all Driver or FL ASIO on Windows but its totally playable.